# how to log users connections?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

my app's frontend in Reactjs and Backend have written in NodeJs with MongoDB.

I use the **Morgan** package to log the **rest request** in the Nodejs console.

```
const requestLogger_with_morgan = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, 'log/requests.log'));
```

Like this:

> GET /api/users/5dbd0e97848e13261c80412f 304 - - 4.526 ms

Now I want to save these logs in the table separately for each user at DB.

what the best way to do this?

and what should I use libraries?
finally, I want to show to each user her logs of connections.

Answer (score -1):

You must add an attribute in your MongoDB user schema called `logs` in array type .

Every time a user login you push the date in this array. You'll be able to do whatever you want with this stored data